# How to change the sizes in a Matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, height

I have a matrix in r whit the same size in all the spaces but I want to make the number 12 smaller in his height. This is my matrix.

```
x11(width = 10.98425,height = 8.503937)

m = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,12,2,3,4,5,6,12,2,7,8,9,10,12,2,7,8,9,11,12), nrow=6, ncol = 5)
layout(m)
layout.show(12)
```

And this is the result of that matrix

[image]

Can you help me please thank you :3

Comment: Something like this? `layout(m, heights=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, .5))`

Comment: Yeaaaaah thank you so much :3